# ToString[SetPrecision[x,1.2]] doesn't work as expected

Tags: output-formatting, arbitrary-precision

2nd Code Block demonstrates failure in comment of output

```
    {x,y,z}=GeoPositionXYZ[OneWeb-0452]["XYZ"]; Print["Current Postion of OneWeb-0452 is(x=",SetPrecision[x,2],", y=",SetPrecision[y,2], ", z=",SetPrecision[z,2 ]," meters from the Center of the Earth"]
(* Current Position of OneWeb-0452 is(x=3.1*10^6, y=5.8*10^6, z=2.4*10^6 meters from the Center of the Earth*)

(* versus *)

Print["Current Position of OneWeb-0452 is(x=", 
 ToString[SetPrecision[x, 2]], ", y=", SetPrecision[y, 2], ", z=", 
 SetPrecision[z, 2 ], " meters from the Center of the Earth"]

(* Current Positiion of OneWeb-0452 is(x=      6
3.1 10, y=5.8*10^6, z=2.4*10^6 meters from the Center of the Earth*)
```

Comment: Try `ToString[SetPrecision[x, 2], InputForm]`. See the first examples [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToString.html).

Comment: Re-expands to Machine Precision so not the desired result.  However, "TraditionalForm" did the trick!

Comment: Your code doesn't work for me. I'm not sure what the input to `SetPrecision` is. I also wonder about the title: `SetPrecision[x, 1.2]` does not appear in your code.

Comment: Are you looking for `NumberForm` rather than `SetPrecision`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `ToString[SetPrecision[x, 2], TraditionalForm]`